# CSS Selector doesn't come in effect on h1 tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tags

I am making a website which is supposed to have a big header as the main description. I have embedded the description in a `<h1>` tag and I used CSS to make the tag have a Monsterrat font. But no matter how many times I reload the page, it doesn't come in effect.

```css
/******************** CLASS SELECTORS  ********************/
.phone {
    height: 500px;
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -120px;
}

/******************** ID SELECTORS  ********************/
#title {
    background-color: #2978b5;
}

/******************** TAG SELECTORS  ********************/
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Black', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Techno-Log</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Techno-Log</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Reviews</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Brands</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>Get the best technology updates and product news.</h1>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="phone" src="https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f8ebc300be77fed7b88aaf4/960x0.jpg?fit=scale" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the default Bootstrap font with a different class

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

/******************** CLASS SELECTORS  ********************/
.phone {
    height: 500px;
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -120px;
}

/******************** ID SELECTORS  ********************/
#title {
    background-color: #2978b5;
}

/******************** TAG SELECTORS  ********************/
h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.montserrat{
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Black', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Techno-Log</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Techno-Log</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Reviews</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Brands</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1 class="montserrat">Get the best technology updates and product news.</h1>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="phone" src="https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f8ebc300be77fed7b88aaf4/960x0.jpg?fit=scale" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: @GenisBillionaire Not in the snippet, so it must be an implementation problem on your part.

Comment: can you show me an image of your snippet?

Comment: @GenisBillionaire Just click the 'Run code snippet' in my answer

Comment: Oh so it looks like that? I see. Thanks :P

Comment: Also, if th monserrat font is not avalaible on your computer, it won't show if you did not call it from your CSS (@font-face)  or via google font https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?selection.family=Montserrat tools `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap');`

Comment: @GenisBillionaire Glad to help :)